# Why setInterval is not working after auto tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used JQuery `.tab()` to built a tab , and I wanted to make it could be continuous auto switching tab , but it did't work after loaded the page. 
I found out that when I imported this external script, the auto tab didn't work.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/solar_energy/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Here is my code, please help me to know why it didn't work. Thx.

```js
var n = 3, //number of tabs
  i = 0; // current tab

$("#tabs").tabs();
setInterval(function() {
  i = (++i < n ? i : 0);
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", i);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="1.html">tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="2.html">tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="3.html">tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have a look http://jsfiddle.net/htr0onm5/ all working fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code work fine take a look at **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VmmW/865/)**, just make sure that your `jquery-ui` is included correctly and check your console if there's an error.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="1.html">tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="2.html">tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="3.html">tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
var n = 3, //number of tabs
  i = 0; // current tab

$("#tabs").tabs();
setInterval(function() {
  i = (++i < n ? i : 0);
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", i);
}, 2000);
```

If your code work without `<script type="text/javascript" src="/solar_energy/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` i guess that you're already included jquery somewhere in your code.

Comment: I found out that when I import the external script below, the auto tab function won't work, do you know why?<script type="text/javascript" src="/solar_energy/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Make sure that the link to your jquery librairy is correct (check network tab in developpers console), and also check that there's no other includ of the jquery.